# How to deploy latest changes to github pages from Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages, gatsby

I followed the [guide as per this link at gatsby docs](https://v1.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploy-gatsby/#github-pages).

Everything went well & the site was hosted at github-pages. However, all the subsequent changes in my master branch are not being pushed to gh-pages branch. Github branches pages shows that the 'gh-pages' branch is ahead by 12 commits & behind master by 21 commits.

I understand the 'gh-pages' branch is production branch for deployment, so I cannot simply merge master into 'gh-pages'.

Can someone please clarify what is 'gh-pages' branch being built & deployed from? How do I get 'gh-pages' in sync with the master branch.

Thanks

Comment: Did you run `npm run deploy` again by any chance after making changes?

Answer (score 1):

Github is building/deploying to gh-pages from the source branch that you [can set in settings](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/). Actually there is a mention about it in gatsby docs you provided:

> If this is not successful, make sure that gh-pages is set as the source branch in your repository’s Settings -> GitHub Pages and then re-run `npm run deploy`.

As for syncing: you can mirror `gh-pages` with `master`, but i'd rather use any of these branches straight up, without syncing, just treat the branch in GH pages settings as your main and "production-like" branch.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The github pages are being built off 'gh-pages' branch, which is a production branch, i.e. Gatsby processes & churns out pages ready for github pages to deploy. I cannot simply select 'master' branch as source branch. I am getting confused by the 'gh-pages' npm package and the same named branch. I have run `npm run deploy` multiple times, however, it appears to be deploying the same site to github branch of the same name. The npm script within packages.json is: `"deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"`.

Comment: "it appears to be deploying the same site to github branch of the same name". I think that you somehow mixed the build branches. To investigate further you need to check your github settings and mark what branch mentioned there, afterwards you can try to deploy again and notice what was pushed to what branch to github. Keep track on how exactly `gh-pages` package works using [docs for your commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#optionsbranch).